# How to remove a reference tag from a header

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am writing a program to scrape a wikipedia page using python. My code works fine except for one small detail.

When I output the results, the header shows the little number on right top corner of the website's reference.

Can I please know how to output the header without this number?

Comment: share the url so we can see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give you a proper solution when you haven't provided the url of the wikipedia page you are scraping but I can tell you this line is the problem:

```
proper_value = [dp.text.strip() for dp in value]
```

It is just adding any text to the proper_value list, you can filter it by adding a conditional to your list comprehension like this:

```
proper_value = [dp.text.strip() if not dp.find('sup') else dp.text.strip().replace(dp.find('sup').text,'') for dp in value ]
```

Which will exclude the superscript text ("sup" tag) information